# libgdx player speeding up when bullets on screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

I am coming across a very strange problem with a game I am creating in libgdx. When my player fires a bullet, he (unwantedly) speeds up.

At first I thought it might be because I was somehow passing in references to the player's position when creating the bullet, rather than creating a new position, but I've scanned the code over and over and I don't think that's what's causing it.

I believe it may be *something* to do with the way delta timing is being handled, as the behavior is exaggerated on lower spec devices:

-Running as a LwjglApplication on my desktop computer, the problem is either not noticeable or doesn't occur at all
-On a quad core 1.4Ghz tablet the problem is noticeable but, whilst annoying, it doesn't impact the workflow of the game
-On a single core 1Ghz phone, the problem is very noticable, so much so that the player will usually end up being considerably faster than the bullets on screen (and will occasionally will fall through rectangles he shouldn't)

My GameScreen.render class looks like this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) 
{
    if((!(this.isPaused)&&(!(this.renderInProgress))))
    {
        this.renderInProgress = true;
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.35f, 0.15f, 0.1f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
               //update players with delta passed in
        controllerPlayer.update(delta);
               //update bullets with delta passed in
        for(Bullet b:world.getLevel().getBullets())
        {
            b.getController().update(delta);
        }
        world.getLevel().updateObjectStateTimes(delta);
        rendererWorld.render();
        rendererOverlay.render();
        this.renderInProgress = false;
    }
 }
```

controllerPlayer looks like this:

```
    // Processing the input - setting the states of Bob
    processInput();

    // If Bob is grounded then reset the state to IDLE 
    if (grounded && bob.getState().equals(State.JUMPING)) 
    {
        bob.setState(State.IDLE);
    }

    // Setting initial vertical acceleration 
    bob.getAcceleration().y = GRAVITY;

    // Convert acceleration to frame time
    bob.getAcceleration().mul(delta);

    // apply acceleration to change velocity
    bob.getVelocity().add(bob.getAcceleration().x, bob.getAcceleration().y);

    // checking collisions with the surrounding blocks depending on Bob's velocity
    checkCollisions(delta);

    // apply damping to halt Bob nicely 
    bob.getVelocity().x *= DAMP;

    // ensure terminal velocity is not exceeded
    if (bob.getVelocity().x > MAX_VEL) {
        bob.getVelocity().x = MAX_VEL;
    }
    if (bob.getVelocity().x < -MAX_VEL) {
        bob.getVelocity().x = -MAX_VEL;
    }

    // simply updates the state time
    bob.update(delta);
```

Bullet.getController.Update():

```
    public void update(float delta) 
    {
        checkCollisions(delta); 

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(Bullet.this.direction==DIRECTION.RIGHT)
            Bullet.this.position.add(10*delta,0f);
        else
            Bullet.this.position.add(0-(10*delta),0f);

        Bullet.this.bounds.setX(Bullet.this.position.x);
        Bullet.this.bounds.setY(Bullet.this.position.y); //not needed?
    }
```

And here's where the bullets are created:

```
        this.fireReleased();

        if(world.getLevel().getBullets().size() < Bob.MAX_BULLETS)
        {
            Bullet b = bullPool.obtain();
            Rectangle bobRect = rectPool.obtain();
            bobRect.set(bobRect.set(bob.getBounds().x, bob.getBounds().y, bob.getBounds().width, bob.getBounds().height));

            Vector2 bobCent = new Vector2();
            bobRect.getCenter(bobCent);

            this.sndFire.play(0.4f);
            if(bob.isFacingLeft())
            {               
                b.set(bobCent, DIRECTION.LEFT, world);
                world.getLevel().addBullet(b);
            }
            else
            {
                b.set(bobCent, DIRECTION.RIGHT, world);
                world.getLevel().addBullet(b);
            }
        }
```

As requested, I have uploaded a sample project at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/318066/star-assault.zip

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem in a small example program, without any extra stuff not related to the problem?

Comment: It seems, like it is something delta time specific. Do you multiply the `speed` wit hthe `delta` time? Do this for player and bullets! Also limit the `delta` to `Math.min(delta, 1/30.0f)`, meaning, that if FPS are lower than 30, delta time is limited to the delta time of 30 FPS.

Comment: have added link to sample projects which recreate the issue

Comment: It sounds to me as if you have a static variable for velocity that is shared between bullets and the player when it shouldn't be. Is velocity declared as static in your 'bob' class?

Comment: Bullets don't reference any velocity - they travel at a fixed rate of 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, **first off**: your code is very messy. Your BobController class (which I don't think really needed to be separated from Bob, although that is not really an issue, just seems pointless) is doing way too much. The two things I'd definitely put in a different class is input and collision detection. And try to avoid things like updating Bob's position during collision detection, it makes it unorganized and hard to find.

Sorry for so much talk about that, now for the problem itself. Notice how your bullets have a speed of 10, and Bob's max velocity is 15. That means he should be able to accelerate past them. But then why doesn't he do so at 60 FPS?

The part of the movement that doesn't depend on `delta` when it should is `DAMP`. At 60 FPS, it decreases the speed 60 times; at 20 FPS, only 20 times. This meant that at high FPS, `MAX_VEL` can never be reached at all. Eventually Bob reaches a speed where his acceleration every frame equals the speed damping takes away from him. If we assume fixed FPS of 60, this means that he accelerates by `ACCELERATION * delta` = 20 * (1/60) = 0.33 every frame. When this acceleration takes him to horizontal speed of 3.33, the damping takes away 0.33 as well - an equilibrium is reached. So the *actual* maximum velocity is 3, not 15. At lower FPS rates, this value is higher.

So the **first part of fixing it** is simple - change `MAX_VEL` to 3.

That is a significant improvement, but Bob is still a bit faster at lower framerates. This is because his position is updated in `checkCollisions()` after applying acceleration, but before applying `DAMP` and `MAX_VEL`. So if Bob is at his maximum velocity of 3, his actual velocity is a bit larger depending on how much he accelerates every frame.

**The second fix** - put `checkCollisions()` to the end of `BobController.update()` (or at least after applying `MAX_VEL`).

After that, the maximum speed is the same for all framerates, but damping is still framerate-dependent - he stops much quicker on high framerates. This is easier to fix by changing this to a proper deceleration - we decrease Bob's speed by a fixed amount every second - e.g. by 10. This is the value we give `DAMP`. For applying it, we decrease the absolute value of Bob's velocity by `DAMP * delta`, or set it to 0 if it's less than that. That is the **third fix**.

All changes in code:

```
private static final float DAMP = 10f;
private static final float MAX_VEL = 3f;

(...)

public void update(float delta) {

    (...)

    // apply damping to halt Bob nicely 
    float decel = DAMP*delta;
    if (Math.abs(bob.getVelocity().x) < decel) {
        bob.getVelocity().x = 0;
    } else {
        bob.getVelocity().x -= decel*(bob.getVelocity().x < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    }

    (...)

    // checking collisions with the surrounding blocks depending on Bob's velocity
    checkCollisions(delta);

    // simply updates the state time
    bob.update(delta);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Sorry about the missing assets; I thought I had included everything needed for the code provided. In line 160 bob's velocity has delta applied to it with the line bob.getVelocity().mul(delta); An easy way to recreate the behaviour is by adding a Thread.sleep(100) to the .render function in GameScreen.java

Comment: Strange, from the behavior when giving a fake delta, Bob definitely seemed delta-independent (bullets were faster/slower with higher/lower deltas, Bob stayed the same). I'll take another look when I have time tomorrow..

Comment: Okay, what I said so far was completely wrong, I only added the fake delta to the call to the bullets' update method. I figured it out now, posting an answer soon.

Comment: Great I look forward to it. :) Yea the bullet code is fine as far as I can tell, it's pretty simple. It's Bob that's the problematic one

Comment: Look up, I edited this answer 30 mins ago to remove the pointless stuff while adding the correct fixes :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the update... your updates do fix the bob vs bullets speed issue, but unfortunately, like Chase's suggestions, they break collision detection and jumping

Comment: Then I think you can just move updating Bob's position to the end of update() outside the collision logic while keeping the collision logic where it was. (Trying out at the moment)

Comment: How does it break collision detection? The only issues I can find (weird landing - Bob teleports a bit higher then falls down, similar behavior when touching walls) happen on low framerate and also happen with your original code, so it doesn't seem to be related. Is this what you meant or is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: you're right... it did happen in my original code. I've got so many versions of this code right now I've lost track!

Comment: To fix that one, instead of setting velocities to 0 when they'd result in collisions, you could calculate what position Bob should reach (right next to a block) depending on his direction, and either set his position there (while nullifying velocity) or set the velocity so it brings him right to that spot.

Comment: thanks... I will try and figure that one out. The jumping issue is more of a priority, though. I figure that one should be *relatively* easy (famous last words). I'd imagine it's something to do with mulling the amount his jump is increased by.

Answer (score 0):

previous velocity = 0;

from no movement to going right

```
delta = 0.5;   
bobv = (velocity=0 + (20 * delta)) * 0.9
bobpixels = 9 * delta
bulletv = 10 * delta
bulletpixels = bulletv
```

still going right, now we hit max velocity (15).

```
delta = 0.5;
bobv = (velocity=9 + (20 * delta)) * 0.9
bobpixels = 15 * delta
bulletv = 10 * delta
bulletpixels = bulletv
```

still going right, already at max velocity, can't go any faster.

```
delta = 0.5;
bobv = (velocity=15 + (20 * delta)) * 0.9
bobpixels = 15 * delta
bulletv = 10 * delta
bulletpixels = bulletv
```

still going right, delta drops.

```
delta = 0.1;
bobv = (velocity=15 + (20 * delta)) * 0.9
bobpixels = 15 * delta
bulletv = 10 * delta
bulletpixels = bulletv
```

still going right, delta drops more.

```
delta = 0.01;
bobv = (velocity=15 + (20 * delta)) * 0.9
bobpixels = 13.68  * delta
bulletv = 10 * delta
bulletpixels = bulletv
```

So if I found all your math (centralize this stuff like I said) it looks like you are okay unless the delta gets small enough that bob doesn't maintain a speed of "15". In the first part bob accelerates and gets to 1.5 times the speed of the bullet but at the end when the delta drops it looks like the ratio becomes 1.368 to 1. The problem is how you try to accelerate bob up to his top speed.

To fix all this. Start by ripping out all your bob velocity code. Remove all acceleration logic. Make bob go at a fixed speed to start with and make sure the problem is gone. I'd recommend defining a global base speed, for example 10 meters per second. Have bullet and bob get that speed and multiple it by their percentage. Bob is globalSpeed * 1.5f, bullet is globalSpeed * 1.0f;

When you render you'll multiple the objects speed by delta to figure out how many pixels they've moved since the last frame. Test on the device you see the biggest problems with. Once it is all working add in acceleration code. We need to keep track of how long we bob has been going in the same direction. You'll need bob to have:

```
int direction = 0; // -1 for left, 0 for still, 1 for right
float timeInSameDirection = 0f;
final float timeToTopSpeed = 100f; //find the number that works for you
final topSpeed = Globals.topSpeed * 1.5f;
```

Now when you update bob you'd do something like:

```
if(currentDirection == direction) {
    timeInSameDirection += delta;
} else {
    timeInSameDirection = delta;
    direction = currentDirection;
}

float speed = 0;
// are we moving
if(direction != 0) {
    Interpolation interpolation = Interpolation.linear;
    float accelRatio = timeInSameDirection/timeToTopSpeed;
    accelRatio = accelRatio > 1 ? 1 : accelRatio;
    float speed = interpolation.apply(0, topSpeed, accelRatio);
    speed = direction == -1 ? -speed : speed;
}
```

The cool thing about this is that you can change out the Interpolation and you'd get a completely different feel to bobs acceleration (btw this is sometimes called tweening). With only a little more work you could add deceleration by also keeping track of the topSpeedReachedInCurrentDirection and timeSpentDecelerating.

Note that bob's top speed is 15. This is meter per second or some other game world speed. This is not the same as pixels and since each frame doesn't display at exactly the same delta from the last we need to convert bob's world speed into pixels per frame. Basically `pixelsMoved = speed * NUMERIC_CONST * delta;` Adjust NUMERIC_CONST to your desired pixels to meters ratio.

Comment: what do you suggest is causing the problem? also as the player can accelerate and decelerate, while the bullet runs at a fixed speed, the ratio surely *should* change?

Comment: what formula would you suggest? If I use Bob's formula for the bullet then the results will still work out the same: ((Velocity [10] + Acceleration [0] * delta) * damp[1] will give exactly the same results as Velocity[10] * delta

Comment: It'd start with the simpler formula (delta * NUM). Just don't put it in a bunch of places, put it in a central method that all objects call. That way you can change it if you want and the effect will be global. It would even let you have a "play at 2x speed" option to your game.

Comment: I don't really understand how taking out vital parts of Bob's movement calculations are really going to solve this issue in the long term? The problems will still occur as soon at the formula is expanded back to its current state

Comment: Your bob object speed changes when you add a bullet. If I had to make a guess this is because as you add more artifacts the delta changes. You have different formulas that take delta as an input - as delta changes you can't expect the ratio of those formula's output to remain the same.

Comment: but the bullets are always updated directly after the player and the same delta is passed into both functions - I have updated the source in my question to clarify

Comment: Argh, so `checkCollisions` contains some important parts

Argh part2.. more important parts in bullets, update method

Comment: How you use delta (and the previous velocity of bob that was factored using a different delta) is the problem. If your delta remained the same (no change in on screen assets or really powerful hardware) you'd be okay but as your onscreen assets change on less powerful hardware you are more likely to have larger differences in delta from one render to the next.

Comment: so, considering that Bob *needs* to accelerate, and the bullets *need* to be a fixed speed, what would you suggest I need to do?

Comment: still doesn't work (I presume I'm supposed to add bob.getPosition().add(speed,0); to the end of your routine?)

Comment: Think about it. The top speed is 15. If bob is going full speed does he always travel 15? That "speed" is the meters per second or whatever unit you are using for your world. Convert bob's speed to pixels per frame using delta. Do the same for bullet, 10 is bullet's meters per second, not pixels per frame.

Comment: yea sorry I missed that. Had applied it to the bullet but not Bob. Ok it seems to work now. I will just do a little more testing and then accept your answer

Comment: doesn't work - breaks jumping and collision detections, and the acceleration is more like a car than a person running

Comment: You aren't trying here. I tell you that you have a problem with your math and you complain about having to take out the broken parts. I tell you about versatile acceleration using tweening and you complain about the acceleration being too car like. Did you try changing the acceleration duration (timeToTopSpeed) or the tweening algorithm (Interpolation.X)?

If movement speed is good now and doesn't fluctuate when the delta changes then what does that tell you? It *should* tell you that you also have problems in your jumping and collision code.

Comment: I've spend 2 days trying, listening you telling me my code is broken and giving me no advice as to what's wrong. You tell me to throw everything away and start again - for what? So I can waste another 2 days when I've added everything back in and it still doesn't work. "You have a problem with your math" - I'd figured that much out before I posted the question. Yes I tries changing the acceleration duration - if I lower it, he accelerates like a slow car. If I higher it he accelerates like a fast car.

Comment: The "car" feel is the tweening algorithm.

Comment: right; so adding that isn't really helpful to resolving my situation. Right now I have an algorithm that moves Bob very nicely, in exactly the way I want him to move. The only (albeit large) problem is that it doesn't seem to be respecting delta times correctly. You've helpfully proved that the formula is flawed with your examples, but you haven't made a positive suggestion about how to fix it other than "start again"

Comment: Your algorithm can't handle delta so take it out. Try removing the first delta from you bob code or turn it into a const. The previous bob velocity that you reuse each frame needs to be delta free. After you calculate bob's world velocity then make a copy and use delta to convert world velocity to pixels per frame but keep them separate so when you reuse velocity on the next frame it isn't off if the delta changes.

Comment: So.. I have changed bob.getAcceleration().mul(delta); in the update method to bob.getAcceleration().mul(NOTDELTA); (which is a constant value). Then instead bob.getPosition.add(bob.getVelocity()), I have declared a new Vector2 as ((bob.getVelocity().x) * delta, (bob.getVelocity().y * delta)); this works but now bob can't jump and his collision detection seems to be 'x blocks out', depending on the value of NOTDELTA. If I change the two occurances of bob.getVelocity().mul(delta); in checkCollisions() to bob.getVelocity().mul(NOTDELTA); then nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: Try only changing a little of your `checkCollisions` and see what happens:

    Vector2 bobWorldVector = new Vector2(bob.getVelocity());
    bob.getVelocity().mul(delta);
    //...
    // un-scale velocity (not in frame time)
    //bob.getVelocity().mul(1 / delta);
    bob.setVelocity(bobWorldVector);

Comment: Now bob just falls through everything

Comment: @LairdPleng Stackoverflow isn't about `debug and correct my code`. It is a question and answer plattform. Chase gave you the solution to your problem ("delta time is messing your movement code up"). Now it is up to you to use this. Play arround with the values in your formulas, rewrite your collision detection (i actually rewrote mine about 5 times and i am stil not satisfied) and see whats happening. It is a lot better to understand HOW the problem is being solved, instead of copying working code.

Comment: Thanks... another helpful comment. I've spent days 'playing around' with the formulas and rewriting collision detection, and only end up in a bigger mess. Chase did *not* give me a solution - I posted in my question that I believed it was due to delta. I would LOVE to understand HOW the problem could be solved. The fact that I *DONT* understand how it could be solved is the whole reason I'm posting it here. Why would I post a question when I already understand how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have an older version of your game, where this problem does not exist? If not copy this and remove the code, until you cannot see he problem anymore. Then start from there. It is sometimes easier to rewrite some code, then change existing, not working code to working code, as the errors are hard to find.
Another thing you could try is to post it on `java-gaming.org`, as there is a section called `debuging question` section. Maybe they can help you there